# For Google Analytics Event Tracking, how can I capture the id of an <a> tag using onclick event

Tags: google-analytics, dom-events

I have 10 link buttons on my web page. Each button pertains to a unique city. Each link button has an id attribute containing the name of the city. Each link button contains an onclick event which is recorded/tracked in Google Analytics Event Tracking. However, I haven't figured out how to capture the location from the unique id attribute. See example code below.

In short, I want to dynamically capture the value of the id attribute of the `<a>` tag as the Event Label in Google Analytics? FYI: In the code below, the Event Label is sending `event.target.href` to GA. This is where I want to capture the id value.

Here's the code:

```
<a id=“location-city-example” onclick=“ga(‘send’, ‘event’, ‘button’, ‘click’, event.target.href);” href="/apply" class="btn btn-rj">apply now</a>
```

[image: screenshot of the issue]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mmm... I think this would work

```
onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'click', this.id);"
```

Note that I would stick to using "straight" quotes rather than the "smart" quotes as in your original code. The latter does funny things sometimes.